# Display Name / Description - An In-App Purchase has been returned

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My In-App Purchase item was rejected

Something wrong with **Localizations**

I have one item which is used for app supporting (user can donate to a developer if he wants)

I tried to set next strings

- Display Name: "**App developing support**"
- Description: **"MY APP NAME" developing support**

But reviewer rejected because of them

Comment: Do you have localisations for you IAP to match all of the localisations for your other app metadata?  Perhaps they don't like the word "Support" - It implies that the user is paying for "help", which would be a service delivered outside the app and therefore not suitable for IAP.  You could use the word "Thanks" or "Tip"

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, actually I have Chinese in my app too

Comment: So you must make sure that you have localisations for your IAP metadata for each language supported by your app and your main app metadata

Comment: @Paulw11 but still red icon was set for all languages https://postimg.cc/image/xoakn5qqj/ I edited English localization and become yellow and item is again waiting for review, so I'm not sure if it has something to do with Chinese localization